# CRM 2011 - Sharepoint 2010 Integration - Create all folders

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

We want to install "Sharepoint" at our client, but I don't know how we should do the transfer of all notes.  Because we need to write a service that will create all folders and put the "notes" into the sharepoint.  The "CRM 2011"-DB is getting too large and they want some "Search"-functionality.

So what are the best steps to undertake, for creating a connection between the CRM & Sharepoint? We want the following :

1. All accounts should have a folder with all their notes
2. All contact should have a folder with all their notes
3. All folders need to be created (is their something we can use from microsoft?)

I'm new in the "Sharepoint"-world, so a small push in the back would help a lot.  I know how to set your "CRM" to use "Sharepoint", but how could we do the initial load of all folders and the move of annotations/attachments to Sharepoint.

Is it save to activate sharepoint for over 25.000 accounts in CRM 2011?

Comment: SharePoint can be a scary beast at the best of times, and when doing a "non-standard" (in the way that it isn't the one-click way, the scenario you're describing is still fairly common) I'd suggest getting a SharePoint developer to look at this instead of trying to do it on your own :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Tobias that you should get somebody who really knows SharePoint to comment on the SharePoint implications, but I can help with the CRM side.

Unfortunately when you move your notes from the `annotations` table to SharePoint you're going to lose some of the out-of-box notes functionality in CRM. The nice neat "Notes" section on each page will no longer work, and unless you've got a *very good* SharePoint dev you will probably have a clunky replacement for the notes functionality.

I would be **very** hesitant to move your notes to SharePoint, in effect you're splitting your database in an arbitrary way. A potential middle-road would be to create a custom activity for Notes so that you get roll-ups, searching, etc - but you'll still lose the presentation within your CRM forms.

(As an aside, if size is a concern in your `OrgName_MSCRM` database double-check your MSSQL tasks and ensure transaction logs etc are being cleaned up correctly; if you regularly import or bulk-delete data you can end up with some pretty unwieldy log files and unused space inside your database files)